# Compare data in first column of a delimited file and print out unique found in second file

Tags: perl, shell

I need help to come up with a working perl script that performs same functions as 
SORT command:`sort –t’;’ –k1,1 File1.txt File2.txt File2.txt | uniq –u`

I have two files that are delimited by semi-colon.  I need to extract out unique rows based only uniqueness of first column (numeric) fror File2.txt (differences rather), the other column2 and column3 are irrelevant in the meantime.

File1.txt (master file)

```
123;winter;season
456;fall;season
789;autumn;season
321;summer;season
654;dry;weather
987;cold;weather
```

File2.txt

```
123;winter;season
456;fall;season
789;autumn;season
321;summer;season
369;march;month
147;september;month
```

Expected output (369 & 147 are not in File1.txt)

```
369;march;month
147;september;month
```

so far I have written but it prints out the file two;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# create names lookup table from first file
open(DATA, "<File1.txt") or die "Couldn't open file File1.txt, $!";
my %names;
while (<DATA>) {
    (my @data)= split /;/, $_;
     $names{$data} = 1;
   last if eof;
}

# scan second file
open(DATA2, "<File2.txt") or die "Couldn't open file File2.txt, $!";
while (<DATA2>) {

    print if /^(\d+)/ && not $data[0];
    }
}
```

I am still having a hard time understanding array and hashes. Any help to improve my code will be appreciated.  Please add comments or point out any mistakes I have...thanks in advance.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not far off.

- In the first loop you put the semicolon-separated fields in array `@data`, and then write

  ```
  $names{$data} = 1;
  ```

  but `$data` is a separate variable altogether and is undefined at this point. You want

  ```
  $names{$data[0]} = 1;
  ```

  which uses the first element of the `@data` array
- In the second loop you test `$data[0]` which no longer exists because you declared `@data` inside the upper loop. Since your regex *captures* the first field in `$1` you can just say

  ```
  print if /^(\d+)/ and not $names{$1};
  ```

  and your program will work

It is also *essential* to `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program. That measure would have produced some warning messages that helped with your errors above. You should also use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`. And your `last if eof` line is unnecessary because the `while` condition will exit the loop for you anyway.

Here's a rewrite of your program with these fixes applied

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $f1_fh, '<', 'File1.txt' or die "Couldn't open file File1.txt: $!";
my %names;
while (<$f1_fh>) {
    my @data = split /;/, $_;
    $names{$data[0]} = 1;
}

open my $f2_fh, '<', 'File2.txt' or die "Couldn't open file File2.txt: $!";
while ( <$f2_fh> ) {
    print if /^(\d+)/ and not $names{$1};
}
```

**output**

```
369;march;month
147;september;month
```